# PyInstaller and OpenEXR - exe crashes

Tags: python, crash, exe, pyinstaller, openexr

I am using PyInstaller 3.3.1 and OpenEXR 1.3.0 in my project.

I create single file executable with --onefile option.

---

This works as intended:

```
import sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    print("hello world")
```

"hello world" is simply output into console and program closes.

---

This on the other hand makes exe crash (no errors are displayed):

```
import sys
import OpenEXR

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    print("hello world")
```

---

I tried debugging the program, to see if OpenEXR module is being properly included in exe. It is.

---

1. What can be the other reason of the crash?
2. Is there any way to make the exe tell me why it crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround to the problem. Instead of working with OpenEXR directly, I used [pyexr](https://github.com/tvogels/pyexr) - the wrapper library over OpenEXR. Exe doesn't crash anymore.